# How to register subdomains on dnsmasq

Tags: dns, subdomain, dnsmasq

how can I register subdomains of my web development server into my DNS automatically?

I mean, I wouldn't like to edit the DNS config file, but send something from the client that says 'Hey, I have a subdomain here'. Is it possible? Other way, how can I register a subdomain, example redmine.DEV01 into my dnsmasq installation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use dnsmasq wildcard. For example if you want to force all subdomains of DEV01 to machine with ip 192.168.1.2 just add this line to dnsmasq config:
address=/.DEV01/192.168.1.2

Comment: Is it possible to let the DEV01 server publicly it's subdomains on the DNS automatically?

Comment: Good question. I thought you only need subdomains for localhost or lan. I don't know how to make public subdomains similar way. In fact I have [similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/545957/subdomains-for-server-behind-nat)

Comment: Yes it's for LAN, but I would like to allow my DEV01 server to publicly its subdomains to the DNS automatically (I have a server running dnsmasq), I mean, to do not have to edit DNS config file? I wonder if that is possible or I will always need to force it editing the DNS config file.